# Getting "Bad Request" on the post request to Django Rest-Api using serializers

Tags: django, ajax, rest, api, bad-request

I am trying to save data into a model using django-rest framework. I have already written the api, it works fine when i access it directly using the url to api. But I get a bad-request error when i try to post data using ajax.
If it is working fine when data is inserted using the api interface, it should work fine when data is inserted using ajax....but instead i am getting a bad request.

here is the AJAX request method(Jquery):

```
$("form").submit(function(event){
           event.preventDefault();

            var this_ = $(this);
            var formData =this_.serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url: "/api/forum/posts/{{ post_question.thread_id.id }}/create",
                data: formData,
                method: "POST",
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log("successfully returned");
                    console.log(data);
                    displayPosts();

                },
         })
```

Serializers are as follow, in api/serializers.py :

```
class ThreadModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    created_by = UserDisplaySerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
       model = Thread
       fields = '__all__'


class PostModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    posted_by = UserDisplaySerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
       model = Post
       fields = '__all__'
```

Models for the Post and Thread are as follow in models.py:

```
class Thread(models.Model):
    thread_subject = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    posted_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    forum_id = models.ForeignKey(Forum, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Post(models.Model):
    post_message = models.TextField()
    thread_id = models.ForeignKey(Thread, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    parent_id = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    posted_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    posted_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and finally the API view is like this, in api/views.py:

```
class PostCreateApiView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = PostModelSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

    def perform_create(self, serializer, *args, **kwargs):
        thread_id = self.kwargs.get('thread_id', None)
        thread = get_object_or_404(Thread, id=thread_id)
        parent_post = get_object_or_404(Post, thread_id=thread_id, parent_id__isnull=True)

        serializer.save(posted_by=self.request.user, parent_id=parent_post, thread_id=thread)
```

and url route is as follow in api/urls.py :

```
    path('posts/<int:thread_id>/create', PostCreateApiView.as_view(), name='post_create'),
```

Hopefully I am able to make the problem statement clear, need help.
When I create a new post using the api url directly, example :

http://localhost:8000/api/forum/posts/4/create

I get no errors and post is successfully inserted in the database.

But when I try to insert the data using the template(ajax), example :

http://localhost:8000/forums/thread/4/

I get a bad request like following :

```
Bad Request: /api/forum/posts/4/create
HTTP POST /api/forum/posts/4/create 400 [0.02, 127.0.0.1:40630]
```

Need help, I have tried hard, but can't find the solution. 
Awaiting reply. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem as you: Just a 400 Error with no further information.

Although i dont know what your Problem is exactly i can tell you that adding an error function to your ajax request will help you debug it.

The reason is that you are not actually causing a python error, you are just making a request that Django Rest Framework thinks is wrong. It will tell you what is wrong in the response which is returned under a 400 status code and thus not shown in the ajax success function but in the error function.

```
$("form").submit(function(event){
       event.preventDefault();

        var this_ = $(this);
        var formData =this_.serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/forum/posts/{{ post_question.thread_id.id }}/create",
            data: formData,
            method: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("successfully returned");
                console.log(data);
                displayPosts();

            },
            error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log('ERROR')
                console.log(jqXhr)
            },
     })
```